# Как я могу добавить данные в Plist?

Tags: словари, xcode, ios

Помогите разобраться с Plist! Создал, немного заполнил. Никак не могу записать туда данные программно. Написал примерно такой код:

NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary;
[myDictionary setValue:@"You-Win" forKey:@"key5"];
NSString* plistPath = [­[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyPlist" ofType:@"plist"];
[myDictionary writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];

Код вроде выполняется, но захожу в свой Plist и не вижу изменений.

Answer (score 1):

вы не видите изменений потому что вам нельзя писать непосредственно в бандл, т.е. код сам по себе правильный, но вот прав на запись ваше приложение в этот plistPath не имеет, нужно где-то в другом месте хранить плист. По вопросам куда можно и нужно писать вам сюда - [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010672-CH2-SW4) . Как получить адрес папки документов - см. здесь [Using The Document Directory To Store Files](http://www.ios-developer.net/iphone-ipad-programmer/development/file-saving-and-loading/using-the-document-directory-to-store-files)

Answer (score 0):

В документации все разжовано с примерами: [Quick Start for Property Lists](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/PropertyLists/QuickStartPlist/QuickStartPlist.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000048i-CH4-SW7)